# Understanding prototyping and augmentation

Tags: javascript

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcWQ8/1/) to help me in my understanding of JavaScript prototyping and inheritance.  The comments tell the story.

```
//From Douglas Crockford's "Javascript: the good parts":  a helper to hide the "ugliness" of setting up a prototype
Function.prototype.method = function(name,func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
}

function SomeFunc(value) {
    this.setValue(value);
}

//Inherit the function (to me this conceptually the same as adding a member to a class)
SomeFunc.method('setValue', function (value) {
    this.value = value;
    return this;
});

try
{
SomeFunc(1);
}
catch(e)
{
    alert(e);
}
```

Why do I get an exception?  Are my notes correct in that what JavaScript calls inheritance is to a Classical programmer simply adding a new member to a class?  What is the difference between augmentation and inheritance?

Comment: For a start, have a look at [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_constructor_prototype).

Comment: You forgot a `new` before `SomeFunc(1)`

Comment: @Kru - That fixed the error.  Why is the new needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are my notes correct in that what JavaScript calls inheritance is to a Classical programmer simply adding a new member to a class?

No, not really. In JavaScript, we have prototype-based inheritance. That means an object has a reference to another certain object, its prototype. Whenever a property of an object is accessed, the prototype chain is searched for this property. So if the the object does not have this property itself, its prototype is inspected for this property and so on.

```
+------------+    +-------------+
|  Instance  |    |  Prototype  |
| __proto__ -+--->|  __proto__ -+-->...
| foo        |    |  bar        |
+------------+    +-------------+
```

`Instance` has both, the `foo` and `bar` properties.

Now, if you have a constructor function, you can create many instances (objects) referring to the same prototype. When you now add a new property to that prototype, all instances will have this property too (due to the prototype chain).

This is often done to dynamically extend instances but it is only one consequence of prototype inheritance, it is not inheritance itself.

> What is the difference between augmentation and inheritance?

Inheritance would be to set the prototype of an object to a certain object so that it is in the prototype chain. Augmentation is just copying properties. The object would *own* that property then:

```
+------------+
|  Instance  | 
| __proto__ -+--->...
| foo        |    
| bar        |
+------------+
```

> Why do I get an exception?

Because you are calling `SomeFunc` like a "normal" function, not like a constructor function. In that case, `this` will refer to `window`, which does not have a `setValue` method.

Instead you want to call it with the [`new` operator *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/new), to create a new instance:

```
var instance = new SomeFunc(1);
```

If called this way, `this` will refer to an empty object which inherits from the constructor function's `prototype` property (`SomeFunc.prototype`).

[MDN has a nice article about `this` and what it refers to in certain situations.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this)

And if you look at what `method` is doing, you see that it adds a new property to `SomeFunc.prototype` (`this` refers to `SomeFunc`):

```
this.prototype[name] = func;
```

In fact, was the first part of your code is doing is what I mentioned above: By extending `Function.prototype`, you add a new property to each function and this lets you call `SomeFunc.methods` later.

---

**Further reading:**

- MDN - [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_constructor_prototype)
- MDN - [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
- MDN - [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this)

Comment: You forgot the `new`. ;) +1 though.

Comment: ...ah, I see you were busy building your fancy graphical illustrations. :)

Answer (score 0):

try instead:

```
new SomeFunc(1);
```

because this is the case when prototype works